# why autofocus does not work on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tx"><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text" class="last" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("#tbl").on("blur", ".last:last", function(){
    $("#tbl").append('<tr><td><input type="text" autofocus/></td><td><input type="text" class="last" /></td></tr>');
});
```

As you can see in the above mentioned code, I am trying to append a row to the table when last cell of last row loses focus. The above code works fine, but now I want to focus the first cell of newly added row, when it is created. So, I would like to ask that why html5 `autofocus` does not work in my case?

Here is the link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/8zzcdxfn/10/)

Comment: I don't think your jsfiddle works.

Comment: create a full fiddle

Comment: @Danieboy Sorry, I forgot to update my fiddle, here is the new link: https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/8zzcdxfn/10/

Comment: @gayathri Sorry, I forgot to update my fiddle, here is the new link: jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/8zzcdxfn/10

Comment: @MehranTorki It works as expected, but the autofocus does not work

Comment: I added  $("#tbl").append(function(){
    $('last:last', this).focus();
});   and it appears to work the first time.  But this doesn't explain why autofocus doesn't work sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your script this works fine.

```
<script>
$("#tbl").on("blur", ".last:last", function(){
    $("#tbl").append('<tr><td><input type="text"  class="focus_this" autofocus /></td><td><input type="text" class="last" /></td></tr>');
    $(".focus_this").focus();
    $('.focus_this').removeClass('focus_this');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But that does not work. I have tried it just now. Can you please post working sample for jsfiddle?

Comment: @Mehran Read question properly, he has mentioned that focus the first cell of newly added row, when it is created.  But in your case last cell get focused.

Comment: @LoneRanger sorry to say but I don't see any changes. I mean I don't get focus.

Comment: @LoneRanger I don't know why it does not work on jsfiddle? But when I tried it in a file in my computer then it works fine. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @LoneRanger answer I would like to add why `autofocus` is not working.

`autofocus` automatically get focus when `page loads`. In your case page is not get loaded but only DOM gets changed. Read this http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-autofocus.php

Comment: Thanks  for the link.